# Short story - beautiful boys are an alien species

Tags: story-identification

This would be fairly recent - within the last 20 years or so.

A woman researcher suspects that there is an alien species living among us. They are beautiful, unattached young men, not hostile or violent. They stay awhile in one place, work temporary jobs, and sooner or later move on and disappear. Their girlfriends, of course, get pregnant.

There is no guarantee that this is any sort of conspiracy on the part of the "boys", although the scientist believes this is the case, and they may even be a human subspecies which has evolved to take advantage of a social/ecological niche. They only make up about 2% of hunky young men. Since they are biologically identical with humans, identification is based entirely on sexual attractiveness - which has certain obvious flaws.

The researcher eventually falls for one of her subjects. Who disappears after she becomes pregnant.

Comment: Oh man, this one's familiar, but I'm blanking on the anthology. Did you read it in a book? Magazine?  Any other info?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Almost certainly a "Year's Best" collection or some other anthology. Although I may originally have run across it in a SF magazine such as IAMSF.

Comment: Didn't they leave the impregnated women with some kind of financial compensation?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Nope. They just work regular jobs, as young men do - construction, tend bar, etc. If they really are just what they seem, hunky young men, they show the classic young man's unwillingness to be tied down. The story never definitively decides _what_ they are. The story just raises the tantalizing possibility that such a race of parasites exists among us.

Comment: Could it be ['Beautiful Boys' by Theodora Goss](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1496094)? I don't have the text to see.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents - Bingo. Write it up as an answer and get your points. Can be read here http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/beautiful-boys/

Comment: For what it's worth, I was remembering Pohl's We Never Mention Aunt Nora, which is about an alien who serially impregnates different women and leaves them financially well off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I need a profound quote here about the question containing the answer...

"Beautiful Boys" is indeed the title, a short story by Theodora Goss. Republished and made available online by [*Lightspeed SF*](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/beautiful-boys/).

Comment: It goes to show what a difference a few words makes when Googling. "Beautiful boys" is useless. "Beautiful boys gross" is useless. "Beautiful boys theadora gross" works perfectly.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast "Beautiful boys gross" may be useless, but "Beautiful boys goss" works perfectly.

Comment: Good job! Sadly that wasn't the one I was thinking of, so I will have to continue to obsess on it.

Comment: @user14111 - Damn it!